# Page No Longer Prompting w/ USN & PSW on HTTP Authenticated Page

Tags: password, http, template-manager

Page is set to "yes" for http authentication. Worked fine for the last week. Went to show a client how it worked during a training session and it was no longer working.

Thoughts? No errors, just not requested usn and password and is taking users to page that should be protected via password/usner.

Comment: Had you already authenticated from that browser? Most modern browsers remember HTTP auth tokens unless you reset or quit the app (I think it depends on the browser).

Answer (score 0):

@ Derek,

Thanks, that was the issue! I'll have to look into forcing the browser to not save tokens.

Thanks